# Hive Error - The type 'TypeAdapter' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am working with Hive models where I have assigned the `@HiveType(typeId: x)` properly to each class even though when I running

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

I am getting error in generated file for Models with typeId 2 to 10. Below is the error; these models from typeId 2 to 10 were added later, so I have to delete previous generated file and rerun the command, and Hive Generated TypeAdapters for Type 0 and Type 1 i.e Module And UserData there is no issue in it.

```
The type 'TypeAdapter' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given. 
Try adjusting the number of type arguments to match the number of type 
parameters.dart(wrong_number_of_type_arguments)
```

[image: The type 'TypeAdapter' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given. Try adjusting the number of type arguments to match the number of type parameters.dart(wrong_number_of_type_arguments)]

```
This issue is for only models with typeId:2 to typeId:10
```

Below are my models with `@HiveType` and `@HiveField`.

File 1 Models:

```
      @HiveType(typeId: 0)
      class UserData {
        @HiveField(0)
        String token;
        int userID;
        @HiveField(1)
        String firstName;

        UserData({
          this.userID,
          this.firstName,
        });
      }

      @HiveType(typeId: 1)
      class Module {
        @HiveField(0)
        int moduleID;
        @HiveField(1)
        String moduleName;

        Module({
          this.moduleID,
          this.moduleName,
        });
      }
```

File 2 Models:

```
    @HiveType(typeId: 2)
    class ExamData {
      @HiveField(0)
      int moduleID;
      @HiveField(1)
      int broadcastID;

      ExamData(
          {this.moduleID,
          this.broadcastID,});
    }


    @HiveType(typeId: 3)
    class Section {
      @HiveField(0)
      int sectionID;
      @HiveField(1)
      String title;

      Section(
          {this.sectionID,
          this.title
      });
    }

    @HiveType(typeId: 4)
    class Question {
      @HiveField(0)
      int questionID;
      @HiveField(1)
      String title;

      Question(
          {this.questionID,
          this.title});
    }

    @HiveType(typeId: 5)
    class Type {
      @HiveField(0)
      int typeId;
      @HiveField(1)
      String name;

      Type({this.typeId, this.name});
    }

    @HiveType(typeId: 6)
    class Answer {
      @HiveField(0)
      int answerID;
      @HiveField(1)
      String title;

      Answer({this.answerID, this.title});
    }

    @HiveType(typeId: 7)
    class FileInfo {
      @HiveField(0)
      int fileID;
      @HiveField(1)
      String type;

      FileInfo(
          {this.fileID,
          this.type});
    }

    @HiveType(typeId: 8)
    class Meta {
      @HiveField(0)
      String tempFieldForHiveTest;
      @HiveField(1)
      List<Tag> tags;

      Meta({this.tags, this.tempFieldForHiveTest: ""});
    }

    @HiveType(typeId: 9)
    class Tag {
      @HiveField(0)
      int tagID;
      @HiveField(1)
      int moduleID;

      Tag(
          {this.tagID,
          this.moduleID,});
    }

    @HiveType(typeId: 10)
    class SectionStatus {
      @HiveField(0)
      Section section;
      @HiveField(1)
      bool isAttempted;
      SectionStatus({this.section, this.isAttempted});
    }
```

Below are my dev dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^1.1.1
  build_runner: ^2.0.6
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my question on github in Hive Repo, thanks to Matheus Baumgarten, https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/811

```
I was having a model called Type;
```

When Hive tries to generate an adapter it uses the name of your model + Adapter suffix; like

```
class TypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Type> {}
```

The Generated adapter is then in scope and dart can't figure out that the TypeAdapter that the other classes are trying to extend comes from Hive.

So by adding a adapterName solved the issue,

```
  /// In your models file
  @HiveType(typeId: 5, adapterName: "MyTypeAdapter")
  class Type {
     /* ... */
  }
```

which generated file will have the Type model named as MyTypeAdapter which will implement our Type model

```
    class MyTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Type> {
      @override
      final int typeId = 5;

      @override
      Type read(BinaryReader reader) {
        final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
        final fields = <int, dynamic>{
          for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
        };
        return Type(
          typeID: fields[0] as int,
          name: fields[1] as String,
        );
      }
    }
```